# Including dependencies in cx_Freeze setup.py file

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am trying to get all dependencies included in my executable created by `cx_Freeze` in Python so that if the executable is run on any machine having no packages/modules installed, there is no error. Yes, we can include the packages explicitly as I have done. But I need to have something that includes all dependencies automatically.

I have used this code for `setup.py`

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


includefiles = ["log_filename.txt"] # include any files here that you wish
includes = []
excludes = []
packages = ["lxml"]

exe = Executable(
   script = "app.py", # the name of your main python script goes here 
   initScript = None,
   base = None, # if creating a GUI instead of a console app, type "Win32GUI"
   targetName = "app.exe", # this is the name of the executable file
   copyDependentFiles = True,
   compress = True,
   appendScriptToExe = True,
   appendScriptToLibrary = True,
   icon = None # if you want to use an icon file, specify the file name here
)

setup(
    name = "ap", # program name
    version = "0.1",
    description = 'app',
    author = "",
    author_email = "",
    options = {"build_exe": {"excludes":excludes,"packages":packages,
      "include_files":includefiles}},
    executables = [exe]
)
```

I used `find_packages()` but it causes some error.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 29, in <module>
    executables = [exe]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 362, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 112, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 24, in __init__
    distutils.dist.Distribution.__init__(self, attrs)
TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with Distribution instance as first argument (got Distribution instance instead)
```

please help

Comment: what is "some error"?

Comment: Error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 29, in <module>
    executables = [exe]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 362, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 112, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 24, in __init__
    distutils.dist.Distribution.__init__(self, attrs)
TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with Distribution instance as first argument (got Distribution instance instead)`

Comment: what happens if you don't put "include_files" on that dictionary?

Comment: Also, instead of "packages": packages, try: "includes", lxml is on the stdlib, it's not a package.

Comment: cx_Freeze should find imported dependencies automatically - `packages` and `includes` are only there for when it can't detect things, which usually happens when something is loading modules dynamically, like a plugin system.

Comment: @Thomas K : That means if I run the executable on a machine that doesn't have any packages or modules installed then the application would run fine as it has included all the imported dependencies?

Comment: That's the idea, yes. It doesn't always work perfectly, but you only need to list the packages that it can't automatically detect are used.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was a great help